# Operations on rrule from iCal

Tags: calendar, icalendar, rrule

iCal allow defining a recurring event through the rrule. There may be many desired operations on rrule. Operations may include set operation (union, intersection..) & temporal operation(like before,after,in). For example, I may want to know whether an rrule entails another rrule. Is there any such library. I went through many libraries, I found that mostly they mostly generate the events. Is there any library which perform some reasoning and operations on rrule

Comment: If you describe your actual use case you probably get better results. There may be better solutions than you currently think of.

Comment: I believe the only sane way of checking if the elements generated by one rule are also generated by another rule is by actually generating all the elements. The problem is that for many recurrence sets there are more than one rrule to generate the same results. Of course that also often depends on the date you start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [google-rfc-2445](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-rfc-2445/) project (Java) focuses on RRULEs and calculating their dates.  While it hasn't been updated in a very long time, I use this library for one of my projects and it works very well.